# Is there a logical way to decide whether to proceed with mediation analysis on the basis of your data?

Tags: mediation

I am running a study wherein there are multiple DVs (`Y` - objective performance on tasks tapping into multiple dimensions of a construct),  4 IVs (`X` - which could probably be collapsed into a single IV - self report data) and a single Mediator (`M` - psychophysiological data - which is not manipulated). It is hypothesised that `M` will mediate the relationship of `X` and `Y`, following the expectation that both `X` and `Y`(s) will significantly relate (in the same direction) to `M`. However, initial  analyses revealed that no significant relationship exists between `X` and `M`, nor `M` with `Y`(s), contrary to the hypothesis.

Intuitively, there is very little reason (if any) to expect that there would be any mediation effect in my data. Following Preacher-Hayes method (since Baron-Kenny method is considered outdated), ignoring regression steps for path a or b would lead to many mediation models to run (due to multiple DVs). I am trying to figure out if there is a logical way to inspect my data prior to inform whether or not i should proceed with running mediation models, as my intuition seems too closely aligned to Steps 2 and 3 of the criticised Baron-Kenny method (i.e., 'must be significant relationship between `X` and `M`, and `M` and `Y` 'before proceeding with analysis. Basically, I don't want to simply  'blindly' run a bunch of mediation models on the basis of theory/previous literature, when my data is telling me something different (and screaming 'nothing to see here'!).

Would it be enough to justify not running them on the basis that the hypothesis regarding mediation was following the prediction that both `X` and `Y` would be significantly associated (in the same way) with `M` in our sample?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.